# Where can I find the XML documentation for Android?

Tags: android, xml

Is there a place where I can find the XML documentation for Android? For example, when I want to find the XML attributes for   I found it by using Google and ended up on this webpage: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html

Now is there a single page with all the documentation available similar to the Javadoc webpages or 
http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html for the XML attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find **xml attributes** for the particular widget, you can always select the android.widget in the api section and you can always select the particular sub item in that which is available in the below section(For example I have selected TextView). So, you can view respective xml attributes in the **XML Attributes** Table. Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) as I have described in the example.

It was explained in a clear manner about the feature of that particular attribute too. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't have any specific API set for XML interaction. You can simply look at Java documentation for XML:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/package-summary.html